# how to improve the rendering time of a PDF file (Django)?

Tags: django, pdf, digital-ocean

- I have a django web platform hosted on digital ocean, the platform
  works fine, but rendering large pdf files (average 100MB) takes a
  long time (average 1:30 min)
- These are the resources in digital ocean:

  -2 vCPUs 4GB/80GB Disk
- How can we improve rendering time?

This is how it looks when it takes time to render the pdf (disable the main menu of the pdf to avoid downloads)
[image]